# Make a list of the letters in a string in java

Tags: java, substring, string-length

Im new to java and im learning how to play with the substing option.
 Im trying to make a program that starts with a Menu that gives 3 options.

1. Write a string
2. Makes a list of the characters in the string in
   order(Ex: Letter 1:H Letter 2:E Letter 3: L Letter 4:L Letter 5: O)
   and at the and it will say the number of characters and spaces the
   string has.
3. Exit

I made this code:

```
public class LEtras {
static String frase="" , letra="",salida="";
static int Espacios=0, noletras=0;
public static void Frase() {

    frase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese una frase");
    int x = frase.length();
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        letra = frase.substring(x);
                if(" ".equals(letra)){
                     Espacios++;
                } else {
                   noletras++;
        }             
    }
     Menu();
}
public static void imprimir() {
    int f = frase.length();
             for(int i=0;i<f;i++){
                 letra = frase.substring(f);
                 salida+="Letra " + (i+1) + ": "+letra;
             }
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,salida,"Salida",2);
}
public static void Menu(){
          int op = 0;
    do{
        op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menu principal" + "\n 1)Frase 2)Datos 3)Salir"));
        switch(op){
            case 1 : Frase();break;
            case 2 : imprimir();break;
            default : JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SALIENDO","SALIR",2); break;
        }
    }while(op<=2);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Menu();
}
```

I have a few problems with this code, first one is that at the time of making the list it just prints (Letra 1: Letra2: Letra3:), its not printing the character in the string.Also i dont know how at the end of the string in the 2nd option im going to put the number of spaces and the number of characters. And im also having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Metodos.LEtras.Menu(LEtras.java:43)
at Metodos.LEtras.main(LEtras.java:52)
```

And i dont know what this means since im new to programming. 
Sorry for bad english. And thanks for your help

Comment: Aside: Swing (including `JOptionPane`) [is not thread safe.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)  Practically speaking it won't matter for a small self-teaching program like this.  But as you progress in Java please try to keep in mind that threading concerns are real and have to be dealt with.

Comment: For this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null` looks like you didn't input anything in the input dialog.  If you want to make a bug-proof program you'll have to validate the string that `JOptionPane` returns.  For a simple program like this you could just not leave the input blank when you run the program.

Comment: OK, this one is important and 100% your fault: `letra = frase.substring(x);` This does NOT return a letter.  Something you must do is learn to read documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: Thanks ALOT!!! Your last answer helped me fix the error! Thank you so much!

Comment: Reading the documentation is important.  I almost always re-read the docs every time I use a method in the API, including when I looked it up for that link (I double checked to make sure I did understand how `substring()` really worked).  It can be a pain, but that's how programmer really work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very careful while dealing with the indexes in Strings.You need to remember that index of character starts from 0 and last character of the string falls at the index which less than the length of the string by 1.

Since your are writing  `int f = frase.length();`, this means f is the length of your string. After this yopur tryng to find substring byt the below statement:

```
letra = frase.substring(f);
```

So, here the value in letra will be null, because at index f you will have nothing in your string(since your string ends at f-1). That is why you are getting ***Letra 1: Letra2: Letra3*** as output.

Similar issue is there when you invoke `imprimir()` in option 2. You are doing :

```
letra = frase.substring(f);
salida+="Letra " + (i+1) + ": "+letra;
```

Again you letra will be `null`. Since `i+1` will be an integer and you are trying to concatenate null with it that is why you are facing `NumberFormatException`